# Making synch and asynch ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am pretty new to ajax and trying to make ajax calls.

I had to use `asynch: false` because if I did not,the control will not wait for results from the `url` and hence renders nothing.Now I need to make another call to another `url`.I do not want ajax to wait for results from `function` while it calls `function2`. How do I do this with current scenriao that I forcefully had to keep `async:off` so that it gets results from servlet first and then tries to render ?

**Problem :**  Data does not render when ajax makes asynch calls.

**What I want:** I want to be able to make asynchronous calls as I have to render charts from different functions using different URL's on this same html page.

**What I do not want:**  I do not want it for wait for function1 first to render it results before moving on to calling `function2`. `function1` and `function2` are independent of each other, use different `url's` to retrieve data and hence shall be called parallel y without wasting time having to wait for one function to complete and render data first.

**What my code is doing :**
1.It fetches data in `JSON` format from a url.

2. Uses google charts api `visualization` to render charts based on data provided in `JSON` format by the `url`.

There is only 1 `function` here so far. But I need to add other to be able to fetch data from another url for another chart.

Here is what I have tried so far :

```
var queryObjectLen="";
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                async: false,
                url : 'http://localhost:8080/Charts/db',
                success : function(data) {
                    queryObject = jQuery.parseJSON(data);            
                    queryObjectLen = queryObject.Details.length;


                  google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});


                  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
                },
                error : function(xhr, type) {
                    console.error("OOPS!, an error Occured");
                    alert('server error occoured')
                }
            });
```

Without using `asynch :false`, the charts are not rendered so I suppose that is because control moves on to render without retrieving data from the url and probably this is why it renders when async is off. However, not I want to retrieve results from two different urls and render charts on those basis. However, I  do not want to wait for one function to go ,fetch data ,render and then move to function2 by which I mean it that it has to be asynchronous calls. Where do I seem to go wrong that I had to force it to be synchronous and what I may do to be able to do that ?

**Edit1:** Here is the complete code in my file:

```
         <script type="text/javascript">

            var queryObject="";
            var queryObjectLen="";
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                async: false,
                url : 'http://localhost:8080/DBCHART/db',
                success : function(data) {

                    queryObject = jQuery.parseJSON(data);            
                    queryObjectLen = queryObject.Details.length;


                  google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});


                  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
                },
                error : function(xhr, type) {
                    console.error("OOPS!, an error Occured");

                    alert('server error occoured')
                }
            });



            function drawChart()
            {


                var arrdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                arrdata.addColumn('string', 'DeptName');
                arrdata.addColumn('number', 'NumberOfEmployees');

                for(var i=0; i<queryObjectLen; i++)
                {
                    console.log(queryObject.Details[i].DeptName);
                    var dept= queryObject.Details[i].DeptName;

                    var emp = queryObject.Details[i].NumberOfEmployees;

                     arrdata.addRows([
                        [dept,parseInt(emp)]
                    ]);
                }


    var options = {
                    title: 'Department vs. Number of Employees on Horizontal Axis',
                    vAxis: {title: 'DeptName',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}},
                    'width':400,
                    'height':300
                };
                var option2 = {
                title: 'Department vs. Number of Employees on vertical Axis',
                hAxis: {title: 'NumberOfEmployees',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'blue'}},
                'width':400,
                'height':300
                };

                var option3 = {
                title: 'Department vs. Number of Employees on Pie Chart',
                'width':400,
                'height':300
                };
                var option4 = {
                title: 'Department vs. Number of Employees on Line Chart',
                'width':400,
                'height':300
                };
           var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));//this is altogether a different object
           var chart2 = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
            var chart3 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div3'));
           var chart4 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div4'));
            chart.draw(arrdata, options);
            chart2.draw(arrdata, option2);
            chart3.draw(arrdata, option3);
            chart4.draw(arrdata, option4);
        }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div>
    <div id="chart_div2" style="width: 800px; height: 400px;"></div>
    <div id="chart_div3" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div>
    <div id="chart_div4" style="width: 400px; height: 500px;"></div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you need to re-think your reasoning for `async:false`. It's almost never a good idea. You may have to shuffle some stuff around, but I'd bet you can make it async and still accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: @JoeEnos: I am actually completely new at anything related to client end. Do you mind me posting here rest of the code here (It is not much) if you could suggest what pieces I may need to move ? I am really unaware of client end language.

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't understand the question or what the problem is.  Like Joe said, you should be able to do as many Ajax calls as you want using async if it is coded properly.  Please describe what you are trying to accomplish (in words) with both Ajax calls and you can post more code if that clarifies what you're trying to accomplish.  But, since it looks like you're new here, please make sure you describe the actual goal of your code, not just the problem your current code has so we can help offer the best overall solution.

Comment: @Simrankaur Go for it - we might be able to help you sort it out.

Comment: @jfriend00: Yes, I thought so too but the functionsrender charts on basis of what data was returned by url specified and nothing gets rendered in case I make is an asynch call. Do you mind helping me out if I paste the code here ?

Comment: Please read the edits to my previous comment.  If you fully describe (in words) what you are trying to accomplish, I'm sure we can help.  You may want to read about the [XY problem (asking about solution rather than describing the problem)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and [how to ask a good question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to enhance your changes of getting a good answer.

Comment: @JoeEnos: Updated the question with my code. Could you please have a look at it ? Thanks a ton .

Comment: You posted more code, but still no description of what you're actually trying to accomplish!  We don't just guess what code is supposed to do.  Please describe ***in words*** what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @jfriend00:Sure, I will check that. I apologise if I added an unporductive question on the forum.Thanks.

Comment: @jfriend00: Updated the question and tried to describe it clearly.Could you please check ? Thanks

Comment: Is there a possibility that I get answered or has this question been closed as I see it downvoted ?

Comment: Please list out the exact sequence of steps you want to occur like 1) Do X ajax call, 2) load google stuff, 3) something else, 4) something other.  You're just listing problems with your code.  That is NOT what we want to know.  We want to know what you are trying to accomplish.  Your question has not been closed yet.  The downvote is likely because it is STILL not clear what you are actually trying to accomplish.  Imagine you were writing a specification to hand to a software engineer.  In that specification you would describe the entire goal of the code.  That's what we need.

Comment: @jfriend00:Thank you. I updated it again. Please have a look :) .

Comment: Did I still miss out on something ?As I have been waiting to get answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setOnLoadCallback` function is what's giving you grief right now. This is the initialization function for Google's stuff, kind of like jQuery's `$(document).ready` - you shouldn't be using that in your success handler, but rather wrapping the entire AJAX call:

```
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'http://localhost:8080/DBCHART/db',
        success : function(data) {
            queryObject = jQuery.parseJSON(data);            
            queryObjectLen = queryObject.Details.length;
            drawChart();
        },
        error : function(xhr, type) {
            console.error("OOPS!, an error Occured");
            alert('server error occoured')
        }
    });
});
```

Once you do this, you'll be able to add more asynchronous calls, or do whatever it is you need to do.

Comment: That was awesome :) Thanks a ton.Now my next question is how was I supposed to know this? The documentation does not state it right away :/ Any suggestions on dealing with such problems ?Thanks a ton.

Comment: @Simrankaur - almost any function that involves networking in Javascript that does its job in a callback is asynchronous.  That means the callback is called some time in the future, not right away.  So, when you have several of these, you have to think very carefully what order you want to sequence them in and how you trigger from one to the next.  So, anytime you see a result being offered in a callback function, you should immediately suspect that the operation is asynchronous and then confirm that in the doc.

Comment: @Simrankaur I agree their documentation could use some work - all the samples I saw on their site were very simplistic, never digging into any real-world scenarios like multiple charts, refreshing charts without reloading the page, etc. - so sometimes you just have to take a step back and ask yourself what that example is really doing.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Joe for understanding the question.

Here's a performance improvement on Joe's answer that loads the Google stuff and does the Ajax call in parallel and then calls `drawChart()` when both are done.  This can be done because there's no need to wait for the Google stuff to be done before starting the Ajax call or vice versa.  This uses jQuery promises to make it easy to wait for multiple async operations to be done.

```
// jQuery promisified version of google.setOnLoadCallback()
function googleSetOnLoadCallbackPromise() {
    return $.Deferred(function(def) {
        google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
            def.resolve();
        });
    }).promise();
}

google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
// first promise from the ajax call
var p1 = $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'http://localhost:8080/DBCHART/db'
});
// second promise from loading the Google stuff
var p2 = googleSetOnLoadCallbackPromise();

// use $.when() to know when both promises are done
$.when(p1, p2).then(function(ajaxResult) {
    // ajaxResult is [data, statusText, jqXHR ]
    // so ajaxResult[0] is the data
    queryObject = jQuery.parseJSON(ajaxResult[0]);            
    queryObjectLen = queryObject.Details.length;
    drawChart();
}, function(err) {
    console.error("OOPS!, an error Occured");
    alert('server error occoured')
});
```

And, here's a manually done parallel version (without the use of promises):

```
var remainingCntr = 2;
function checkDone() {
    if (--remainingCntr === 0) {
        drawChart();
    }
}

google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(checkDone);
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'http://localhost:8080/DBCHART/db',
    success : function(data) {
        queryObject = jQuery.parseJSON(data);            
        queryObjectLen = queryObject.Details.length;
        checkDone();
    },
    error : function(xhr, type) {
        console.error("OOPS!, an error Occured");
        alert('server error occoured')
    }
});
```

---

FYI, it feels pretty architecturally icky to me to be stuffing data into global variables and then calling `drawChart()` which uses those global variables.  If this is the only place that `drawChart()` is called, then perhaps the data should just be passed directly to `drawChart()` as arguments.

Comment: @Simrankaur - added a non-promise-based parallel version.